# Linking Qt5.0.2 to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, ide, command-prompt, qt5

I am trying to link Qt5.0.2 to Visual Studio 2012 so I can do some GUI programming in C++ inside the Visual Studio environment. I have Downloaded and install ActivePerl and added Perl to the PATH environment variable and Create Perl file extension. I than downloaded Qt and installed it. I opened my Visual Studio Command prompt and changed to my C:Qt\Qt5.0.2 directory. Inside this directory I have a 5.0.2 folder, Tools folder, License folder, MaintenanceTool files and so on. Once inside of my C:Qt\Qt5.0.2 directory, I inserted this command: configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -platform win32-msvc2012. I get an error saying 'configure' is not recognized as a an internal or external command, operational program or batch file.

I have no idea what this means and what to do. I have been following my instructions from this aticle http://briolidz.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/compiling-qt-with-visual-studio-2010/

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would follow instructions posted here http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: These instructions are similar to the ones I posted above and it still uses the 'configure' command which I still get the error for.

Comment: configure comes as part of MS Visual Studio, but you need to open special  Visual Studio Developer Command prompt to be able to use it instead of regular cmd.exe. Here is an article how to find it on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/04/19/finding-the-visual-studio-command-prompts-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Yes I have been using this command prompt and remain to get the same error. I really don't know why I am getting this error.